# Use concepts or SFINAE to check if class has a templated member function with a std::array parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, metaprogramming, type-traits, c++-concepts

#### Introduction

I want to detect, using concepts and/or type traits, if a class has a member function with a std::array parameter.

For example:
Class below would pass the concept.

```cpp
class OStreamRealizationGood
{
    template<size_t size>
    uint8_t send(std::array<uint8_t, size> array)
};
```

Up until now, I have used a trick for concepts. The trick is defining the size to 0.
So my concept looks like this:

```cpp
template<typename Candidate>
concept OStream = requires(Candidate candidate, std::array<uint8_t, 0> array)
{
    {candidate.send(array)} -> std::same_as<uint8_t>;
};
```

That trick works for a templated function, but it isn't really the thing that I need. It isn't the thing that I need because the class below would also comply, but I would like that it doesn't.

```cpp
class OStreamRealizationBad
{
    uint8_t send(std::array<uint8_t, 0> array)
};
```

#### Question

Is there a way to write this to ensure that `send(array)` is a templated function?

#### Things I tried

I had an idea of using `declval(size_t)` as in the picture below, but that doesn't work for primitive types.

```cpp
template<typename Candidate>
concept OStream = requires(Candidate candidate, std::array<uint8_t, declval(size_t)> array)
{
    {candidate.send(array)} -> std::same_as<uint8_t>;
};
```

Another idea that doesn't work was recursing the concepts:

```cpp
template<typename Candidate, size_t size>
concept HasSendImpl = requires(Candidate candidate, std::array<uint8_t, size> array)
{
    {candidate.send(array)} -> std::same_as<uint8_t>;
};

template<typename Candidate>
concept HasSend = requires(size_t size)
{
        requires HasSendImpl<Candidate, size>;
};
```

#### Additional question

Additionally, I don't understand why the example above doesn't work.

Comment: Why is it necessary that the send function is a template? Also why do you ask a question that is different from the question in the title? It would be better to adjust the question title.

Comment: Firstly I want to preface that I work in embedded development and dynamic memory usage is of the table. I am writing an "interface" OStream which must have a C++ style send and a C style send (i.e., `send(uint8_t& array, size_t size)`). So C++ style function will be preferred, but when the size is not known at the compile time C style function will be called. For C++ style function to work without dynamic memory and be flexible enough it must be templated.

Comment: Yeah, I should re-title the question, the thing is similar questions exist, but they don't solve this problem. They do either the templated function or a member function, or in some cases both, but they don't solve this issue. EDIT: Retitled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to write this to ensure that `send(array)` is a templated function?

You can use the `template` keyword in the constraint to signify that `send` needs to be a template function:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
concept GoodRealization = requires(T t, std::array<uint8_t, size> array) {
    { t.template send<size>(array) } -> std::same_as<uint8_t>;
};
```

[DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/43wH3rDPRfR9yDWv).

Note that this will not reject a type that overloads send with a non-template and a template function: of both are viable candidates in overload resolution, the non-template overload could be the best candidate (given the regular rules of overload resolution).

Comment: That's not quite a solution to the problem... this more of a half-baked work around to the specific case of the problem. I don't believe that there is a general solution to the problem with features available in C++20. Perhaps, once Reflection TS is available then one could write some code that verifies templates...

Comment: As I also believe that a general solution doesn't exist, I will accept this one.