# C++ concept template member function restricted by another concept

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I would like the template method `m` in the `concept` `D` to be restricted by another `concept` `E`, something like this:

```
template <typename t>
concept E = requires(t p_t) {
  std::default_initializable<t>;
  std::copy_constructible<t>;
  std::move_constructible<t>;

  typename t::x;
  requires std::is_convertible_v<typename t::x, int>;
};

template <typename t>
concept D = requires(t p_t) {

  { template <E e> p_t.m<E>() } -> std::same_as<float>;
};
```

but the line `{ template <E e> p_t.m<E>() } -> std::same_as<float>;` does not compile, it generates the error "Expected expression".

If I understood right what is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092701/concept-for-member-function-taking-a-template-parameter-in-c20), it is not possible, but I wonder if someone else knows a way to do it.

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what are the requirements for types that match concept D?

Comment: Note that `std::default_initializable` in the `requires`-clause will always be satisfied, since it only checks the validity of the expression. [gcc-trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/q793hfTW4) also gives warnings about this.

Comment: It is not possible to check at compile time that some function has a particular constraint. However, you could try checking that the function is *not* instantiable with some type template argument that doesn't satisfy the constraint.

Comment: For the presented problem, it does not matter what `D` or `E` are, they can be anything anyone thin it is interested, they are meaningless abstractions. The core is how to use a previous defined `concept` in a template method defined in another `concept`.

Comment: Note I did not ask what D or E mean. I asked to formulate requirements for types that match D in terms of E. For example, "the type must have a member named m which matches concept E" (I have no idea if that's what you really want).

Comment: It is not important for the question

Comment: Of course it is vitally important to the question. Without this information there is no question. "How do I use X" is not an answerable question. "How do I use X to do Y" is. But whatever floats your boat.

Comment: It is a question of abstraction. The role o `D` and `E` are not relevant in this case, that is why I used meaningless letters instead of concrete types.