# template method in a C++ 20 'concepts'

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-templates

I would like to define a `concept` which requires a template method, like

```
template <typename t>
concept event = std::default_initializable<t> && std::copy_constructible<t>;

template <typename t>
concept dispatcher = requires(t p_t) {
  { template <event e> p_t.publish(e &) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};
```

I am using

```
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

which reports `main.cpp:11:5: Expected expression`

in line  `{ template <event e> p_t.publish(e &) } -> std::same_as<void>;`

I've searching and by posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092701/concept-for-member-function-taking-a-template-parameter-in-c20) it seems it's not possible.

Is it really?

Comment: Your case is similar to your link. It is indeed not possible.

Comment: 'dispatcher' can not be limited by one 'event'. It could by multiple 'event' types, like 'template <typename t, event... t_events> concept ...', but I still need 'publish' to be template parameterized by one 'event', like '{ p_t.publish(event &) }...', but this does not compile because 'event' needs a template argument.

Comment: Perhaps another other way to achieve this?

Comment: @canellas It is not possible, but why do you need this? It is not the intended use case of concepts to check whether certain entities exist or not. The intention is to check whether certain _expressions_ are well-formed, so that the template can use them. It shouldn't matter whether the expression is made well-formed by the presence of a single function template or some other overload set.

Comment: @canellas A template specialization with a type `T` that is constraint by `dispatcher` can only possibly call `p_t.publish(x)` for a finite number of types `x`. So why is a constraint on arbitrary type necessary?

Comment: I have a 'template <event... t_events> dispatcher' class, with a 'template <event t_event> publish(...)' method. So, there can be a 'dispatcher<e1,e2>' and a 'dispatcher<e3>' instantiation. Suppose there is a class C1 that needs a 'dispatcher<e4>', and in the program there is a 'using dispatcher_D = dispatcher<e1,e4>', C1 will not be able to use 'dispatcher_D'. So I'd like to make C1 depends on a concept of a dispatcher that publishes 'e4', so that C1 can use 'dispatcher_D'. I hope this could give an idea of what I need.