# Define a method in 'concept' that takes another 'concept' as parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In this concept:

```
template <typename t>
concept connection_c = requires(t p_t) {
  requires std::copy_constructible<t>;

  {
    p_t.write(std::declval<const uint8_t *>(), std::declval<const uint8_t *>())
    } -> std::same_as<communication_status_t>;

  {
    p_t.read(std::declval<uint8_t *>(), std::declval<uint8_t *>(),
             std::declval<uint8_t **>())
    } -> std::same_as<communication_status_t>;
};
```

I would like to use a more elegant and flexible definition for methods `write` and `read`, by not using explicitly `const uint8_t *` or `uint8_t *`.

I thought of defining template parameters for `write` and `read` but I already [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77385556/template-method-in-a-c-20-concepts?noredirect=1#comment136425753_77385556) that this is no possible.

I thought of using some sort of `std::convertible_to` `uint8_t`, but could not get the syntax right neither I know if its is possible.

I thought of using concepts from `iterator`, like `input_iterator` and `output_writable` but could not figure out how or if it is even possible.

Then I came up with this solution:

```
template <typename t, typename t_byte>
concept connection_c = requires(t p_t) {
  requires std::copy_constructible<t> ;

  { p_t.id() } -> std::same_as<tnctt::id>;

  {
    p_t.write(std::declval<const t_byte *>(), std::declval<const t_byte *>())
    } -> std::same_as<communication_status_t>;

  {
    p_t.read(std::declval<t_byte *>(), std::declval<t_byte *>(),
             std::declval<t_byte **>())
    } -> std::same_as<communication_status_t>;
};
```

Is there another way?

EDIT:

So far, that is the closest to what I would like:

```
template <typename t>
concept one_byte_c = (sizeof(t) == 1);

template <typename t, typename t_byte>
concept connection_c = requires(t p_t) {
    requires std::copy_constructible<t> && std::move_constructible<t> &&
                 !std::default_initializable<t>;
       
    requires one_byte_c<t_byte>;    
   {
    p_t.write(std::declval<const t_byte *>(), std::declval<const t_byte *>())
    } -> std::same_as<communication_status_t>;

  {
    p_t.read(std::declval<t_byte *>(), std::declval<t_byte *>(),
             std::declval<t_byte **>())
    } -> std::same_as<communication_status_t>;
};
```

Comment: You’re not requiring that the class being tested declare its members using `uint8_t` (or `t_byte`); you’re just saying that’s the type you’ll provide, which presumably is something you know.  Why is that a problem?

Comment: "_I would like to use a more elegant and flexible definition_": In what scenario exactly can't your initial concept definition work the way you want it to?

Comment: @DavisHerring, I wish I did not have to add a parameter to the concept because I think it would make it easier for 'connection_c' to be used, if the requirements for the method could be defined in the method instead of in the concept

Comment: @user17732522, it can be used in any situation, as far as the code casts it data to a 'uint8_t', which I would like it not to happen.

Comment: @canellas What cast specifically are you concerned about? Please give a concrete code example where using the original concept doesn't work as intended. My impression is that you are somehow misunderstanding how concepts are intended to be used, but without a code example it is difficult to tell.

Comment: @user17732522, if I use the first concept, AFAIK, I would have to use it like this:
'template <connection_c t_connection>
void f5(t_connection &p_connection) {
  std::string msg("hello");
  p_connection.write(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(&(msg[0])),
                                 reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(&(msg[msg.size()])));
}
'

Am I more lost than I supposed?

Comment: @canellas OK, and what do you want instead that doesn't work?

Comment: If you want to require that the type support the same function body without `reinterpret_cast`, then all you need is to replace `const uint8_t*` in the concept by `char*`. And then it makes sense to make the concept a template in the way you showed if you want it to be reusable with different types. But every given point-of-use for the concept will always only require specifically `connection_c<const uint8_t>` or `conncection_c<char>`. It is impossible that a function could ever require the type to satisfy `conncection_c<T>` for _all_ `T`. So there is no problem with your suggested solution.

Comment: @user17732522, it works, I only wish I could define the requirements of the parameter in the method, not in the concept.

Comment: @canellas What do you mean with "_define the requirements of the parameter in the method_"?

Comment: @user17732522, something like
`... { p_t.write(some-way-to-define-requirements-for-the-parameter-type &&parameter_name } -> std::same_as<communication_status_t>...`

Comment: @canellas And what would you expect that requirement to mean? Under what conditions would a type satisfy this requirement?

Comment: @user17732522, one (of others?) requirement for this parameter would be `sizeof (parameter-type) == 1`
I am sorry, but I'll have to pause our very nice conversation now. I'm being called to have dinner.

Comment: @canellas I mean the whole `{ p_t.write(some-way-to-define-requirements-for-the-parameter-type &&parameter_name } -> std::same_as<communication_status_t>` requirement. How do you expect `p_t`'s type needs to be defined in order for this whole requirement to be satisfied (let's say specifically with `sizeof (parameter-type) == 1` as the inner requirement)? I can think of multiple possible interpretations and all of them have issues that would make the idea unusable even in theory.

Comment: @canellas: Why are you using `declval` so much in a `requires` expression? There's an [entire piece of grammar for `requires` expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires) that lets you do that in a way less verbose way.

Comment: Declare objects in `requires` argument list and use them. `std::declval` was meant to be used with `std::enable_if` prior to adoption of concept light.

Comment: @user17732522, I might be trying to use concepts in a way it was not designed to. I'd like to be able to define requirements to the parameters of a method without declaring them in the requires clause of the concept. Something like a virtual method in an abstract class. `template <typename t> concept C = requires (t p_t) { { p_t.m(*requirements-for-param*) } -> std::same_as<void>; };`

Comment: @NicolBolas, if I understood this would demand that a `typename` would be declared for the parameter, right? If so, what I would like is to define a requirement for the parameter without adding a `typename` to the concept

Comment: @Red.Wave, I would like to define a requirement for the parameter without having to add a `typename` for it to the concept

Comment: `requires(t vt, uint8_t const cu8, uint8_t u8)`. Where's the extra `typename` now? Also putting the atomic constraints outside the `requires` clause, you can increase readability: `con_c= std::copy_constructible<t> && requires(/*...*/)//...`.

Comment: @canellas Again, can you give examples of types `t` that should and shouldn't satisfy this concept `C`? How do you determine that these types satisfy the concept?

Comment: @canellas Note that, as the very first comment under this question mentions, the requirement in a concept does _not_ require that a class declares some specific member function with specific parameter types. It only ever requires that certain expressions are well-formed (and result in types satisfying another concept) given the types involved in the expression. How this is achieved is up to the types and concepts do not intent to require specific member declarations in a class type like virtual interfaces do. It would be unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: @Red.Wave, ok I got it that I dont need to add `typename` for each parameter I'll use. But I would like use not a concrete type like `uint8_t` but a more flexible definition, something like `requires (t vt, some-sort-of-requirements-declaration par)` and then to be able to use `par` in the methods declaration.

Comment: @user17732522, I am coming to the conclusion that my idea of concepts usage is not the designed one.